# JXTA Applications on the iPhone

Tags: java, iphone, p2p, jxta

I'm creating a P2P Java application in JXTA, for simple messaging between peers. I want to create a similar program on the iPhone, that will be able to talk with this java JXTA program. Is this possible to do? I know theres JXTA-C which would work on the iPhone, but I'm not sure if the JXTA-C will communicate properly with JXTA-Java.

Is there any way to run java on the iPhone if thats the case?

Any insight would be really helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JXSE (the Java implementation of JXTA) release 2.6 & 2.7 comply with the JXTA 2.0 specifications. Hence, JXTA-C should be compatible with these.

Answer (score 1):

Current released JXTA-C will talk with Java stack. 
The new JXTA-C under development with Peer View 3.0 protocol won't work with Java stack.

Comment: Can the current released Java-C that talks with Java stack work on the iPhone though?